# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy. XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Full body of error message:

```clj
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:8281' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I am using the [cljs-http](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http) package and following the docs. I have set `with-credentials` to false, but the error message is saying it thinks they are set to `include`?

Here is my code:

```clj
  (go (let [response (<! (http/get API-URL
                                   {:with-credentials? false
                                    :headers {"Content-Type": "application/json"}}))]
        (js/console.log (:status response))
        (js/console.log (map :login (:body response))))))
```

How should I structure / what should I include on the request?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the colon from the `Content-Type` header and also the `map` and now the codes works:

```clj
  (go (let [response (<! (http/get API-URL
                                   {:with-credentials? false
                                    :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}}))]
        (js/console.log (:status response))
        (js/console.log (:body response)))))
```